Where has MapIcon gone in Windows MAUI Maps?
I try to migrate a custom renderer for Maps from Xamarin to MAUI
using custom handler.
I need to show a custom icon on the Map in Windows platform,
found multiple examples how to do that in IOs and Droid e.g here
Customize map pins in .Net Maui
from Vladislav Antonyuk
In Xamarin there was a MapIcon class , derived from MapElement
public sealed class MapIcon : MapElement, IMapIcon, IMapIcon2

I could assign an image and add the MapIcon as Element to the Map
mapIcon.Image = RandomAccessStreamReference.CreateFromUri(new Uri(pin.IconURL));
nativeMap.MapElements.Add(mapIcon);

It seems that this is not possible any more or not yet ?
I was also in touch with microsoft support but they simply stopped anwering
MS support QA
They provided me with an example but i was no able to get that compiled.
I followed their guide to add all references.
But it could well be that i use the wrong references
I still see no Image reference definion in Microsoft.UI.Xaml.Controls.MapIcon.
MapIcon x = new MapIcon();

  var mapIcon = new MapIcon
 {
     Image = RandomAccessStreamReference.CreateFromUri(new Uri(iconUri)),
     Location = new Geopoint(location),
  
 };

For your convenience i have created a public git repository of my test code to show my current status.
GIT Repo
I would be very gracefull to get any ideas how to continue.
Bests regards,
Andreas

Do you use the Microsoft.Maui.Controls.Maps? The official document said: The Map control isn't supported on Windows due to lack of a map control in WinUI.

The control it self works but no way to add custom markers / icons. MS support provided example code but that did not work as the image ref in map icon is missing

What does The control it self works mean? In addition, the MapIcon doesn't have an Image property. You can report this migration issue on the github repo.
